# Set a DropDownList SelectedValue to a bound field with sometimes null value

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, selectedvalue

I have a situation where I have a gridview which is populated from a sql table which editing is allowed. For one of the fields, I have it so the user has to select a value from a drop down box in the edit template for the gridview.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department">
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditDepartment" runat="server" 
                         SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Department") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem>Department 1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Department 2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Department 3</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                 </EditItemTemplate>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblDepartment" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

If you select "edit" for a record in which this field already has a value stored in the table for it, no problem. However, if you select "edit" and there is no value in the table for it yet, you get the following error

```
'ddlEditDepartment' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value
```

How can I account for blank or null values in this situation and make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding your DropDownList to a field named "Department" in your GridView's datasource:

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Department") %>'
```

It's kind of a hack, but you could modify the query that populates the Department field of your GridView to account for the nulls (by coalescing them out):

```
SELECT COALESCE(Department, "No department entered") AS Department
FROM YourTable
```

And then just add that as kind of a "default" option in your dropdown:

```
<asp:ListItem>No department entered</asp:ListItem>
```

Comment: I really like the idea, it would do exactly what I want. Though after editing the Select statement, I get an error:

DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Department'. 


`SelectCommand="SELECT ID, COALESCE(Department, 'No department'), Notes FROM Departments"`

Comment: My bad, you need to alias the column, @kyle_13. `COALESCE(Department, 'No department') AS Department`

Comment: Hi @jadarnel27 it worked! The only weird thing was it wouldn't update with the value 'No department' in the Select and in the ListItem. Once I changed it to just `COALESCE(Department, '')` and `<asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>` it worked perfect. It was fine too because I really wanted it to show blank instead of a value, but was odd.

Comment: @kyle_13  That *is* weird.  I'm glad I could help you in the right direction, though =)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to update a record that does not exist.  So, you have a few options, depending on what you want to do.  You could capture the error and display a user friendly alert to the user that they need to create a new record before editing.  Or, you could capture the error and run an insert command if the error gets raised.  Or you could prevent the error from firing all together.  This would be my suggestion.  In your code behind, when the dropdowlist event fires, take the ID and run a query to see if the record exists.  If it does, update it. If not, either alert the user or you could just do the insert then.  If you have a specific question on how to do this, let me know.

Comment: Hi @jason, thanks. What I was basically trying to do was pull in a null "blank" value when updating a record if the field was in fact null, and then update the record with the newly entered value from the dropdown. Without the workaround jadarnel27 gave, it would throw the error.